# How does one test code that uses the Android AssetManager?

Tags: android, testing, mocking, android-assets

I am writing code that will look for specific files in the assets of an Android app and do something with them in a specific order. The asset manager is easy enough to use to that but I'm wondering how to write automated tests of my code.

Example: Let's say I want to print decorated versions of the content of all files that start with 'cool' and are either a .txt or .text extension, in some order. The code is relatively simple, but relies on the AssetManager (this is not compiled or tested code, but a sketch):

```
// Pseudo-code!!!
public void catFiles(Context context, OutputStreamWriter out) {
    final AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
    final String[] files = am.list('myfolder/');
    for (String file: files) {
        // Do some filtering on the list
        if(veryCoolFilterThinger(file)) {
            final InputStream in = am.open(file);

            // Do something cool with the chars from the file.
            out.write(decorateCharsFrom(in));
    }
 }
```

So the question is, how do I test my filtering and how do I test the decorating? The fundamental problem here is that I don't see how to write a mock AssetManager. I can think of two options, which do different types of testing.

Option 1: Don't operate directly on the asset manager, but introduce my own interface, something like:

```
interface ReadableFileContainer {
    public String[] list(String basePath);
    public InputStream open(String path);
}
```

I would then write a mock version of this interface for my tests and a version of it that uses the AssetManager for my production code. Seems fine, but it also feels like AssetManager is already that level of abstraction, so I don't love doing this.

Option 2: Write a bunch of test applications, each with different sets of assets to provide different test cases. This is pretty end-to-end and doesn't add a potentially unneeded layer of abstraction, but does involve writing a zillion test applications (not just individual tests, since they will need different asset directory structures).